# Mockito - spying on real objects calls original method

Tags: java, mockito

Imagine following code:

```
List list = .....
List spy = spy(list);
doThrow(new NullpointerException()).when(spy).get(0);
```

`doThrow(....)` executes `list.get(0)` - this makes no sense at all. I would like to define mock behaviour and not to call a method here..... am I missing something?

EDIT:
List is decorated by CGLIB. When I remove CGLIB proxy Mockito works as expected. Any Idea how to solve such problem when using CGLIB proxies?

Comment: Looks like this is actually just the syntax of mockito, which uses the builder-pattern. (like so many other mocking-frameworks)

Comment: As far as I know Mockito, your code is correct. The documentation says `doThrow` is only for void methods, so you might try again with e.g. `clear()` to see whether this is the problem. But I can't really imagine why `doThrow` shouldn't work on non-void methods like `doReturn` does.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  Yes, you can use doThrow(), even for non-void methods.  The reason why the docs mention void methods is because there's a second syntax for stubbing throws, that doesn't work for void methods, and which is presented before doThrow one in the docs.  The get( 0 ) in your example is only called on the spy, not the real List.  The spy knows that it's in the context of a doThrow, so instead of calling the REAL get( 0 ), it stubs it instead.  Is that what you're asking?  If so, I'll turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: List implementation is already decorated by CGLIB - for example hibernate lazy load. No I create spy on this decorated List - this creates second CGLIB proxy on my List. In this case Mockito proxy is not being executed. I would like to keep existing CGLIB decoration and still be able to use Mockito spy functionality.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Do you think you can post some more of your code?  If you can make it into a full working example (or in this case, non-working example), then I'll put some effort into debugging it and finding out whether this really is a problem with Mockito.

Comment: My project is really big... I will try to create small test case and I will pot it here

Comment: Hey @Maciej which version of Mockito are you using ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.Test;

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

public class MockitoSpyTest {

    @Test
    public void execTest() {

        System.out.println("*** TEST 1 ***");
        System.out.println("Test on unmodified object");
        MySet ms = new MySetImpl();
        ms.set("test value");
        System.out.println("Set contains: " + ms.get());

        // decorate ms1 with easymock
        System.out.println("\n*** TEST 2 ***");
        MySet spyMs = spy(ms);
        doThrow(new NullPointerException("my test nullpointer")).when(spyMs).get();
        System.out.println("Test decorated object with SPY");
        spyMs.set("test value");
        try {
            System.out.println("Set contains: " + spyMs.get());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException - as expected");
        }

        // Enhance call with CGLIB
        System.out.println("\n*** TEST 3 ***");
        System.out.println("Test on CGLIB decorated object");
        Enhancer enc = new Enhancer();
        enc.setSuperclass(MySetImpl.class);
        enc.setInterfaces(new Class[] { MySet.class });
        enc.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
                if ("get".equals(method.getName())) {
                    System.out.println("CGLIB decorated GET call");
                }
                return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
            }
        });
        MySet ms1 = (MySet) enc.create();
        ms1.set("test value");
        System.out.println("Set contains: " + ms1.get());

        // decorate ms1 with easymock
        System.out.println("\n*** TEST 4 ***");
        System.out.println("Test on CGLIB decorated object with SPY");
        MySet spyMs1 = spy(ms1);
        doThrow(new NullPointerException("my test nullpointer")).when(spyMs1).get();
        spyMs1.set("test value");
        System.out.println("Set contains: " + spyMs1.get());
    }

    public interface MySet {
        void set(String val);

        String get();
    }

    public static class MySetImpl implements MySet {
        String val;

        public void set(String val) {
            this.val = val;
            System.out.println("Original SET call:" + val);
        }

        public String get() {

            System.out.println("Original GET call:" + val);
            return val;
        }

    }
}
```

Example above produces output:

```
*** TEST 1 ***
Test on unmodified object
Original SET call:test value
Original GET call:test value
Set contains: test value

*** TEST 2 ***
Test decorated object with SPY
Original SET call:test value
NullPointerException - as expected

*** TEST 3 ***
Test on CGLIB decorated object
Original SET call:test value
CGLIB decorated GET call
Original GET call:test value
Set contains: test value

*** TEST 4 ***
Test on CGLIB decorated object with SPY
CGLIB decorated GET call
Original GET call:test value
Original SET call:test value
CGLIB decorated GET call
Original GET call:test value
Set contains: test value
```

Now the `TEST 2` and `TEST 4` should throw `NullPointerException` on `get` call - based on mockito spy: `doThrow(new NullPointerException("my test nullpointer")).when(spyMs1).get();`

The "TEST 4" does not throw expected exception because it is already decorated with CGLIB - we can also see on the console that CGLIb call is being executed: `GLIB decorated GET call` and not call on spy object. The same effect can be achived when using Spring AOP with CGLIB proxies.

Comment: Excellent example. However, I couldn't see how did this become the answer. I'm getting the same problem when I'm using Spring AOP with Mockito. I couldn't spy on the methods I'm spying on.

Comment: supertonsky, I guess the answer, in a nutshell, is that one cannot create Mockito spies on CgLib-enhanced objects. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.doThrow(new NullpointerException()).when(spy).get(0);
```

I think the problem here is that you are trying to do a partial mock and so you have to have the annotation on your test class:

```
@PrepareForTest(List.class)
```

This may or may not work.  Looking at my code where I test exception handling, I always have done it on a fully-mocked object, not a partially mocked one.  Also, I have made extensive use of PowerMockito when partial mocking, so it is possible that library will do what you need.

Comment: You are confusing things. **A.** Mockito can do partial mocks for some time now through the [Mockito#spy()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)). However Mockito does not mock final classes or final methods, that's where PowerMock might become useful. **B.** You are mentioning `@PrepareForTest(List.class)` which is irrelevant and wrong for 2 reasons : 1. List is an interface so it won't pose problems to mock, 2. This statement alone simply won't work for system classes (without adding an agent).

Comment: This could work, because power mock generates another proxies. I've tried it, and I'am getting javassis exception - it seams that in this case we have conflicts between cglib and javassis

Comment: You what is not nice?  Downvoting people months later.  If the API changes after a year, why punish me for it?